# I get a Black screen when trying to switch SurfaceView in Android's media player for streaming videos

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using this code to test things out: https://gist.github.com/ErikHellman/5840101

This works fine for videos stored on the device. However for streaming videos, I am not able to switch views at runtime.

The streaming url that I am using is this: rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov

The only way I can get it to work is by if I reset my player. However, since I am streaming the video, resetting or releasing the player is not an option for me.

Below is my code for the MainActivity:

```
package com.example.testvideo;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;

@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST = 1001;
    private static final String TAG = "SurfaceSwitch";
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceHolder mFirstSurface;
    private SurfaceHolder mSecondSurface;
    private SurfaceHolder mActiveSurface;
    private Uri mVideoUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SurfaceView first = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.firstSurface);
        first.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                Log.d(TAG, "First surface created!");
                mFirstSurface = surfaceHolder;
                if (mVideoUri != null) {
                    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                            mVideoUri, mFirstSurface);
                    mActiveSurface = mFirstSurface;
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                Log.d(TAG, "First surface destroyed!");
            }
        });
        SurfaceView second = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.secondSurface);
        second.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Second surface created!");
                mSecondSurface = surfaceHolder;
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Second surface destroyed!");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mVideoUri = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Got video " + data.getData());
            //mVideoUri = data.getData();
            mVideoUri = Uri.parse("rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov");
        }
    }

    public void doStartStop(View view) {
        if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
            Intent pickVideo = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            pickVideo.setTypeAndNormalize("video/*");
            startActivityForResult(pickVideo, PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST);
        } else {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    public void doSwitchSurface(View view) {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mActiveSurface = mFirstSurface == mActiveSurface ? mSecondSurface : mFirstSurface;
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mActiveSurface);
        }
    }
}
```